# Hiding Deprecated Error Message Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I was getting this error since I was using a third party application using `mysql_` prefix.

> Deprecated: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in
>   the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /path/to/filename.php on line
>   123

So i tried to hide this error by editing my `php.ini` file. I have tried adding

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED;
```

But that didn't work.

So I tried this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

That too didn't work. What may be the issue? Is it with my `php.ini` file, or am I doing it wrong. Please let me know the correct method to hide this deprecated error message (or what was wrong with the methods i used).

Comment: Although hiding the deprecation warning may work in the interim, it is only a band-aid.  The long term fix is to upgrade that third party application to a version that supports a newer MySQL library.

Comment: Yes I know. But that third party application has no latest version that support mysqli or PDO. I just want to hide the error message for now ans I am planing to rewrite/modify the entire application in mysqli later.

Comment: Are you restarting the server after editing php.ini?  Do you see the changes reflected in phpinfo?

Comment: I am using xampp and I have restarted it all the time I changed the php.ini

Comment: Ok does your phpinfo change?

Comment: this is what in phpinfo   [error_reporting 24567 24567]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to logically AND the negated E_DEPRECATED flag in order to disable it:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. That's weird! Let me investigate this

Comment: Thank you. Is there someway to share my php.ini file here?? So I have to copy and paste the entire code here?

Comment: This is not necessary. It will be too much information.

Comment: What if you put `error_reporting=E_ALL &~ E_DEPRECATED` into your php.ini? (And restart the web server if you work with apache,...)

Comment: Tried that too and restarted my apache server on xampp. But still no use. :(

Comment: @Ranjith Not necessarily. It depends on when PHP triggers the error. If the error occurs on parsing of the file - before the execution of `error_reporting()` it will be required to set it in the php.ini

Comment: @AeJey I've managed to set up a PHP5 machine and tested it. It is working, meaning the above value in the php.ini will suppress the deprecated warning. It will also work if you use `error_reporting()` on top of the file. Seems that something other went wrong on your site.

Comment: Then it may some kind of issue with the php in my system. I will try reinstalling my xampp and will try it again. If not working, i think I have to edit all the mysql statements. :((

Comment: @AeJey If it is a third party software, I would not change the mysql statements. Maybe you can find an alternative for that software?

Comment: Okay. :) Thank you for finding time to help me. Will try reinstalling and will let you know if working or not. If not will try finding another third party application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to deprecate error messages of 3rd third party tools.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: Actually what type of errors you get? Then replace the `&` inbetween `E_ALL` and `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Let me try. Just a minute

Comment: That too is not working. Should I paste my entire php.ini file here? Will that be any issue with my php.ini??

Comment: No. That's not needed here. What `php` version you used? Did you restart the server again..

Comment: PHP: 5.5.11. I am using xampp and I have restarted it all the time

Comment: @AeJey Try this one.. `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE`

Comment: Tried that too mate. Still no use. I think I have to rewrite all mysql statements now. :(